# How to deploy a C# language server, and use WebSockets for communication with client?

Tags: c#, monaco-editor, language-server-protocol

I am trying to host a web page with monaco editor and add intellisense for c#. From what I have found I should use monaco-languageclient with a language server running in a different process and have both communicate over some transport channel, like a web socket.

I have tried many things with no success, but my problem is that I do not know how to start with the Language Server part. I cannot find any specific tutorial on running a C# language server.

If it is possible for anyone to provide a good source for me to get started.

Comment: I managed to run OmniSharp server and communicate with the client, my problem now is that after initialising the client, the server return all false for the capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using omnisharp-roslyn, which has --languageserver flag to work on the ls protocol.